# Upload app on Itunes connect without developer account

Tags: xcode, upload, app-store-connect

I am new to IOS development. I develop a simple app for someone.I don't have an
developer account so he added me on his Itunes Connect account as with the App manager role.
When i try to upload its asks for bundle ID and when i go to developer page it ask me to enroll and all.
So my question is how can i archive my app in this case and upload on the itunes connect.

Okay i think there is some confusion.The case is that I am added as a APP manager in someones Itunes connect account. So Can i upload an app there.

[image]

When i try to do that its aks for a bundle ID and I am not able to create a bundle id from the develper link. though I have already setup the develope account but its not paid yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is your App's Bundle Id.in Xcode go to Project Navigator then select general in identity there is Bundle Identifier further check the image.[image]
And for Developer account on Apple is free just go to this link and click on "Create Account"

https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Faccount%2F&rv=1